# Window auto update doesn't install prerequisite updates

Tags: windows-update

I want to install Security and Quality Rollup updates for .NET Framework 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, and 4.7.2 for Windows 8.1, RT 8.1, and Server 2012 R2 (KB 4338419) on my PC (Windows Server 2012 R2).

I had a look on it and I saw that I need like a prerequisite Windows Server 2012 R2 Update (KB2919355). On that one I see that I need more stuffs like: KB2919442. I tried from windows Update to have the last updates available. After all the updates was installed I took a look and notice that I have (KB 4338419) and (KB2919355) but I don't have KB2919442.

Is that a problem? If I try to install it manually I get "The update is not applicable to your computer."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is best suited for Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355/EN-US](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2919355/windows-rt-8-1-windows-8-1-and-windows-server-2012-r2-update-april-201):

> When you install this update (2919355) from Windows Update, updates
>   2932046, 2937592, 2938439, 2934018, and 2959977 are included in the
>   installation.
>
> Prerequisites:
>
> **To apply this update, you must have the following update installed on
>   Windows RT 8.1, Windows 8.1, or Windows Server 2012 R2:**
>
> **`2919442` A servicing stack update is available for Windows RT 8.1,
>   Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2: March 2014**

Q: Is that a problem? If I try to install it manually I get "The update is not applicable to your computer."

You need not worry about KB2919442 as that was a prerequisite for KB2919355, which is already installed on your server. You can't install the old update now as you already have the latest updates.